# Buildfire - Trouble with Query Selectors

Tags: buildfire

I have two unix timestamps, a start time (startDate) and an end time (endDate). Using the moment function below gives me the very start/end of the day:

```
search = {
  "end": { "$lte": moment(endDate).startOf('day').unix() },
  "start": {"$gte": moment(startDate).startOf('day').unix() }
};
```

I then pass my search into my buildfire function:

```
buildfire.publicData.search(search ,'routes', (err, res) => {})
```

My **res** is an array of objects, each has a **data** property with a **start** and **end** property inside of that:

```
res = [
  {
    data: {
      end: 1503554370297,
      start: 1503554368711
    }
  }
]
```

All results are returning, nothing is being filtered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the docs datastore search https://github.com/BuildFire/sdk/wiki/How-to-use-Datastore#buildfiredatastoresearchoptions-tag-optional-callback

I believe you are not sending the filter correctly.

You are sending:

```
search = {
  "end": { "$lte": moment(endDate).startOf('day').unix() },
  "start": {"$gte": moment(startDate).startOf('day').unix() }
};
buildfire.publicData.search(search ,'routes', (err, res) => {})
```

And it should be more like

```
var options = {
  "filter":{
        "$json.end": { "$lte": moment(endDate).startOf('day').unix() },
        "$json.start": {"$gte": moment(startDate).startOf('day').unix() }
  }
};
buildfire.publicData.search(search ,'routes', (err, res) => {})
```

Basically since your `filter` property in your `options` objectis `undefined` it returns everything

Comment: Thanks that worked. I was looking at the docs here (https://github.com/BuildFire/sdk/wiki/Search-Operators). They don't use $json nor show **filter** as the key but I guess I should have assumed to use filter. Mongo docs kinda threw me off

Comment: Can you give an example of how to use **$where**?

Comment: It would look something like `{filter:{ $where: "$json.credits == $json.debits" }}`

Comment: I'm trying something just like that but I get a 400 error. {"code":"BADREQUEST","message":"error while search for data"}

Comment: Can you paste your options object here so I can review it